# Firefox shortcut keys to switch between tabs

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I know about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> to switch between the tabs inside the Mozilla Firefox browser. I also know about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <index> to access a certain tab from the opened tabs of Mozilla Firefox.

Is any tab regarding arrow keys in order to switch between tabs?

Comment: Note that some shortcut keys are platform-specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No shortcut with arrows, but here is something similar:

**CTRL** + **PgUp/PgDn** will switch to next or previous tab.

Comment: so does CTRL+TabKey for the next Tab - CTRL+SHIFT+TabKey for the previous Tab

Comment: This is what I was looking for. May thx snitzr.

Answer (score 1):

A good add-on for Firefox ist [LastTab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/112/).

Comment: LastTab: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/112/

Answer (score 1):

Use Ctrl+N where N is 1 to 9, you may switch to the Nth Tab immediately.

Comment: Crtl+1-8 is correct, but Crtl+9 is the last Tab

Answer (score 0):

On OS X you can also use option+command+left/right or command+{/}.  I don't know if there are comparable shortcuts on Windows or Linux.  See http://support.mozilla.com/en-us/kb/keyboard+shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like maybe you are looking for the "Ctrl+Tab cycles through tabs in recently used order" in the Firefox settings. If you enable that, pressing the Ctrl + Tab keyboard shortcut will change back to the recently used tabs, rather than cycling through based on the tab's physical position in the window.